# How to convert codes using xlrd with openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x

I have codes that iterate through excel sheets using xlrd, but newer versions of python only use openpyxl. I am not able to use keys like " wb.sheet_by_index" using openpyxl. Is there a way to modify the code below using openpyxl?

```
file_path = os.path.join(root_dir, fname)
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path, logfile=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
sname_found = False
for sheet_index in range(wb.nsheets):
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(sheet_index)
    sname_row = None
    for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
        row = sheet.row(row_index)
        for cell in row:
            cell_text = cell.value
            sname_row = row_index
            sheet_name = sheet.name
            sname_found = True
```

Answer (score 0):

### Raw `openpyxl`

With `openpyxl` you can iterate through the sheets via

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')  # for getting formulas
wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx', data_only=True)  # for getting computed values
for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
    ws = wb[sheet_name]
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
       for cell in row:
           print(cell.value)
           row_index = cell.row  # 1-based index
           col_index = cell.column  # 1-based index

# only to get value
for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames:
    ws = wb[sheet_name]
    for row in ws.values:
       for value in row:
           print(value)
```

### Popular usage: `Pandas`

These days, most people just use `pandas` with `openpyxl` backend to read excel files.

It's very convenient for many use cases, unless you want very fine control for parsing each cell.

With option `sheet_name=None`, this returns a dictionary of DataFrames, where the keys are the sheet names and the value is the corresponding DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

dict_of_dfs = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name=None)
```